# Filter lines based on range of value, using regex

Tags: regex

What regex will work to match only certain rows which have a value range (e.g. 20-25 days) in the text raw data (sample below):

```
[product-1][arbitrary-text][expiry-17days]
[product-2][arbitrary-text][expiry-22days]
[product-3][arbitrary-text][expiry-29days]
[product-4][arbitrary-text][expiry-25days]
[product-5][arbitrary-text][expiry-10days]
[product-6][arbitrary-text][expiry-12days]
[product-7][arbitrary-text][expiry-20days]
[product-8][arbitrary-text][expiry-26days]
```

`'product'` and `'expiry'` text is static (doesn't change), while their corresponding values change. 
`'arbitrary-text'` is also different for each line/product. So in the sample above, the regex should only match/return lines which have the expiry between 20-25 days.

Expected regex matches:

```
[product-2][arbitrary-text][expiry-22days]
[product-4][arbitrary-text][expiry-25days]
[product-7][arbitrary-text][expiry-20days]
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

tested this one and it works as expected:

```
/[2-2]+[0-5]/g
```

`[2-2]` will match a number between 2 and 2 .. to restrict going pass the 20es range.

`[0-5]` second number needs to be between 0 and 5 "the second digit"

```
{2} limit to 2 digits.
```

Edit : to match the entire line char for char , this shoudl do it for you.

```
\[\w*\-\d*\]\s*\[\w*\-[2-2]+[0-5]\w*\]
```

Edit2: updated to account for Arbitrary text ...

```
\[(\w*-\d*)\]+\s*\[(\w*\-\w*)\]\s*\[(\w*\-[2-2]+[0-5]\w*)\]
```

edit3: Updated to match any character for the arbitrary-text.

```
\[(\w*-\d*)\]\s*\[(.*)\]\s*\[(\w*\-[2-2][0-5]\w*)\]
```

Comment: It works, except that it doesn't account for 'arbitrary-text' in between the product id and expiry. 'arbitrary-text' can be anything and of any length, so I'm not sure how your regex will adapt to it. This mod doesn't work: `\[\w*\-\d*\].+?\[\w*\-[2-2]+[0-5]\w*\]g`

Comment: this was missing a forward slash beflore the "g" gloabl... try the latest one .

Comment: Thanks for another try. Unfortunately, the 'arbitrary-text' regex (`\w*\-\w*`) won't work because that text can have any characters (not just alpha or digits).

Comment: The `/g` serves no useful purpose. You only care whether there is a match or not, and not at all about finding any after the first.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up  @tripleee you are right about that .. removed the /g.

Comment: Thanks @NullSoulException. I'll test it with some real data, and accept your answer shortly. By the way, can this regex be made to work if the whole data was semi-colon separated (i.e. the block separator was a semi-colon instead of a new-line)?

Comment: It should work , tested it and it works . It will just ignore the semicolons. Let me know if otherwise.

Comment: Thanks @NullSoulException. It doesn't seem to work if there are semi-colons instead of new-lines separating the data. Scratchpad: https://regex101.com/r/dZ8vC8/2 (btw, I've shortened the regex for simplicity).

Answer (score 1):

Please check the following regex:

[`/(.*-2[0-5]days\]$)/gm`](https://regex101.com/r/eZ2mP6/2)

```
(             # start capturing group
  .*          # matches any character (except newline)
  -           # matches hyphen character literally  
  2           # matches digit 2 literally
  [0-5]       # matches any digit between 0 to 5
  days        # matches the character days literally
  \]          # matches the character ] literally
  $           # assert position at end of a line
)             # end of the capturing group
```

Do note the use of `-2[0-5]days` to make sure that it doesn't match:

```
[product-7][arbitrary-text][expiry-222days]  # won't match this
```

Answer (score 0):

`.*\D2[0-5]d.*`

`.*` matches everything.

`\D` prevents numbers like 123 and 222 from being valid matches.

`2[0-5]` covers the range.

`d` so it doesn't match the product number.

I pasted your sample text into http://regexr.com

It's a useful tool for building regular expressions.

Comment: Thanks will only match the digits. I'd like to match the whole line with that range of days.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one :

```
/(.*-2[0-5]days\]$)/gm
```

try it [HERE](https://regex101.com/r/rX2oL8/3)